# Segmentation fault in embedded application writing to register

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, arm, embedded, gpio

I'm running debian with the 3.14.14 kernel on a Freescale iMX6 arm Processor.

I have this code in an embedded application that gives a segmentation fault.

```
volatile unsigned int& GPIO2IO26CTRL = *((volatile unsigned int*)0x20e0104);
GPIO2IO26CTRL = 0x5;
```

also tried:

```
volatile unsigned int* GPIO2IO26CTRL = (volatile unsigned int*)0x20e0104;
*GPIO2IO26CTRL = 0x5;
```

But I really do want to write 0x5 to location 0x20e0104.  This tells the iMX6 chip that an io line is to be GPIO rather than spi;

How do I get around this?

Comment: Are you doing this in kernel space or in a user program ? (If it's the latter then it's not going to work.)

Comment: it is a user program.  So what is the workaround?

Comment: Unless there is some way to map a physical address into your virtual address space then you will probably need to write a kernel module. Take a look at `/proc` first though to see if there is an easier way.

Comment: there is a /proc/device-tree/soc/aips-bus@02000000/iomuxc@020e0000/hummingboard/hummingboard_spi directory which looks like it could be the right thing; but what do I do with it?

Comment: have you tried mmap?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible from user space (although you may need to be root). The key is remapping the memory into the process's address space.

There is a program called `devmem2` that can do this. Source code is [here](http://free-electrons.com/pub/mirror/devmem2.c).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's help.  In case someone has the same problem I wanted to show my solution.  Much of this code came from the devmem2 from Jan-Derk Bakker.

Here are the two routines I wrote to read and write from memory.

```
static const u_int32_t MAP_SIZE = 4096;
static const u_int32_t MAP_MASK = (MAP_SIZE - 1);

bool CGpio::writeMem(u_int32_t memAddr, u_int32_t &value)
{
    int fd;
    void *map_base, *virt_addr;
    off_t target = memAddr;

    // open the mem file
    if((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1)
        return false;

    // map one page
    map_base = mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, target & ~MAP_MASK);
    if (map_base == (void *)-1)
        return false;

    // map virutial space
    virt_addr = map_base + (target & MAP_MASK);

    // write the value
    *((u_int32_t *) virt_addr) = value;

    // clean up
    bool ret = (munmap(map_base, MAP_SIZE) != -1);
    close(fd);

    return ret;
}

bool CGpio::readMem(u_int32_t memAddr, u_int32_t &value)
{
    int fd;
    void *map_base, *virt_addr;
    off_t target = memAddr;

    // open the mem file
    if((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1)
        return false;

    // map one page
    map_base = mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, target & ~MAP_MASK);
    if (map_base == (void *)-1)
         return false;

    // map virutial space
    virt_addr = map_base + (target & MAP_MASK);

    // read the value
    value = *((u_int32_t *) virt_addr);

    // clean up
    bool ret = (munmap(map_base, MAP_SIZE) != -1);
    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

And here are the headers I used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
```